# ie Automating export with powershell

Tags: javascript, jquery, powershell

I am trying to automate an export from a third party web application with Powershell.  I am able to use the DOM to accomplish everything except the last step.  When the export button is "clicled" a dialog box is opened with three buttons; Open, Save and Cancel.  The dialog does not accept character input, only a mouse click.  I get no information about the box with F12 when the page is open.  How can I click "Open"?  And is this the right forum?

Comment: If the buttons are actual DOM elements Internet Explorer should have provided them with a [`Click()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms536363%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) method. If not I think you need a 3rd party tool like [WASP](http://wasp.codeplex.com/) for sending mouse clicks.

Comment: [UIAutomation](http://uiautomation.codeplex.com/) is good for clicking buttons (if there is no actual method for you to call like Ansgar said).

Comment: Doesn't the "Windows Way" require keyboard access?  I can't a keystroke nor can I set focus.